# How to use properties on onClick from on child and parent component?

Tags: reactjs

I'm now leaning react and having a lot of fun with, but also having my first issue than I cannot solved by myself.

I would like to use a child component to filter on his parent list. I mean I would like to use a child component to filter a list from his parent.. I hope my code would be more understandable than my explications...

Does anyone can explain how should I use onclick in both class and maybe optimize my code ? Thanks

**product.jsx**

```
class Items extends Component {
  state = {
    count: 0,
    carbondioxide: [
      { key: 90, name: "All", value: "All" },
      { key: 91, name: "Still Water", value: "Still Water" },
      { key: 92, name: "Sparkling Water", value: "Sparkling Water" },
    ],
    brands: [
      {
        key: 0,
        name: "Fountain",
        category: "Still Water",
      },
      {
        key: 1,
        name: "Kitchen",
        category: "Sparkling Water",
      },
      {
        key: 2,
        name: "Shower",
        category: "Still Water",
      },
    ],
    filterBrands: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      filterBrands: this.state.brands,
    });
  }

  handleClick = (name) => {
    let filterBrands = [];
    if (name === "All") {
      filterBrands = this.state.brands;
    } else {
      filterBrands = this.state.brands.filter(
        (brands) => brands.category === name
      );
    }
    this.setState({ filterBrands });
  };


  }

 
  render() {
      return (
      <div className="ctg-flex">
        <GroupButtonFilter
          carbondioxide={this.state.carbondioxide}
          onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, name)} //filterBrands onclick


          //onClick={() => {
          //  this.handleClick.bind(this, this.state.carbondioxide.name);
          //}}
          
        />

        {this.state.filterBrands.map((id, brands) => (
            <Item
              key={id.key}
              dataImg={id.imageUrl}
              dataText={id.name}
              dataPrice={id.price}
            />
          ))}

       
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Items;
```

and **GroupeButtonFilter.jsx**

```
class GroupButtonFilter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="group-button">
        {this.props.carbondioxide.map(({ name, value }) => (
          <Button
            key={this.props.carbondioxide.key}
            value={this.props.carbondioxide.value}
            // onClick={this.props.handleClick.bind(this, this.name)} //filterBrands onclick
            onClick={this.props.onClicktest} //filterBrands onclick
          >
            {name}
          </Button>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of issue on your code.

1. You are binding your:

```
onClick={() => {
            this.handleClick.bind(this, this.state.carbondioxide.name);
          }}
```

and your `handleClick` is using arrow function so you can remove bind from this i.e

```
onClick={() => {
            this.handleClick( this.state.carbondioxide.name);
          }}
```

Still its not correct. which is our second point

2. In `GroupButtonFilter` you are expecting `onClicktest`  and while passing in `GroupButtonFilter`  you are sending `onClick` this can reduce to this:

```
<Button
            key={this.props.carbondioxide.key}
            value={this.props.carbondioxide.value}
            // onClick={this.props.handleClick.bind(this, this.name)} //filterBrands onclick
            onClick={this.props.onClicktest} //filterBrands onclick
          >
            {name}
          </Button>
```

3. You need to pass the value that button is clicked but in `onClick` you are sending `carbondiooxide` name. You need to do this. Inside `GroupFilter`:

```
<button
            key={this.props.carbondioxide.key}
            // onClick={this.props.handleClick.bind(this, this.name)} //filterBrands onclick
            onClick={() => this.props.onClicktest(name)} //filterBrands onclick
          >
            {name}
          </button>
```

Here is complete code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class GroupButtonFilter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="group-button">
        {this.props.carbondioxide.map(({ name, value }) => (
          <button
            key={this.props.carbondioxide.key}
            // onClick={this.props.handleClick.bind(this, this.name)} //filterBrands onclick
            onClick={() => this.props.onClicktest(name)} //filterBrands onclick
          >
            {name}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Items extends Component {
  state = {
    count: 0,
    carbondioxide: [
      { key: 90, name: "All", value: "All" },
      { key: 91, name: "Still Water", value: "Still Water" },
      { key: 92, name: "Sparkling Water", value: "Sparkling Water" }
    ],
    brands: [
      {
        key: 0,
        name: "Fountain",
        category: "Still Water"
      },
      {
        key: 1,
        name: "Kitchen",
        category: "Sparkling Water"
      },
      {
        key: 2,
        name: "Shower",
        category: "Still Water"
      }
    ],
    filterBrands: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      filterBrands: this.state.brands
    });
  }

  handleClick = (name) => {
    console.log(name);
    let filterBrands = [];
    if (name === "All") {
      filterBrands = this.state.brands;
    } else {
      filterBrands = this.state.brands.filter(
        (brands) => brands.category === name
      );
    }
    this.setState({ filterBrands });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ctg-flex">
        <GroupButtonFilter
          carbondioxide={this.state.carbondioxide}
          onClicktest={this.handleClick}
          // onClicktest={this.handleClick.bind(
          //   this.state.carbondioxide.name,
          //   this.name
          // )}
        />

        {this.state.filterBrands.map((id, brands) => (
          <div key={id.name}>{id.name}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Items />
    </div>
  );
}
```

here is the demo:https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-fire-zcqc1?file=/src/App.js:0-2168

Comment: I'm having now a error message :  "Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops."

Comment: You have done something wrong check sandbox url and see where you have done wrong

Answer (score 0):

write a function in your parent component

```
handleClick = () => {

/// do your filtering

}
```

pass this handleClick to your child component

```
<GroupButtonFilter handleClickInParent ={this.handleClick} />

   ....

</GroupButtonFilter>
```

then inside your child component

```
 <Button. onClick={() => this.props.handleClick())}>

 </Button>
```